# What is the Ruby String sub function?

Tags: python, ruby, string

I'm trying to convert a Ruby script into a Python script (having absolutely no understanding of the various functions in Ruby) and can't find anything on the Ruby `sub` function.

Here's the function I'm trying to translate:

```
def getCCache(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    local4 = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(arg1 + arg2)
    local5 = 0
    while (local5 < arg3.length)
        temp1 = arg3[local5]
        temp2 = local5
        local5 += local5;
        local4.sub(temp1, arg3[temp2])
        local5 += 1
    end
    return (local4)
end
```

The line I'm having trouble with is `local4.sub(temp1, arg3[temp2])`. What does the `sub` function do? If there's an equivalent in Python I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-sub - I'd have to say that's some horribly obscure Ruby you are converting. Variables called `arg`, `temp` and `local` - in fact it looks like it has been deliberately obfuscated?

Comment: I think it's less deliberately obfuscated and more poorly coded by the original programmer.

Comment: Is some sort of code generator involved in this or did a human actually write that code? Near as I can tell, that whole mess is just a long and confusing way to say `Digest::MD5.hexdigest(arg1 + arg2)`.

Comment: I doubt you did a search for "[ruby sub](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+sub&oq=ruby+sub)", which is the most obvious first step.

Comment: I did, all it brought up for me was references for the gsub method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local4.sub(temp1, arg3[temp2])
```

does nothing. It returns a copy of the string `local4` with the first occurance of the substring referenced by `temp1` substituted by the second argument. **Then the result is discarded** : no variable is assigned to the result.

```
local4 = local4.sub(temp1, arg3[temp2]) #or
local4.sub!(temp1, arg3[temp2])
```

would both do string substitution.

Comment: Interesting. Now I'm really wondering what the hell's going on here. Thanks for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub(pattern) {|...| block } → $_
Equivalent to $_.sub(args), except that $_ will be updated if substitution occurs. Available only when -p/-n command line option specified.
```

`$_` is a ruby global variable and it represents string last read by gets